# My Nextbit Robin (Android 7.1.1) not recognized by Windows 10 x64

Tags: rooting, adb

So I've been trying  to root my Nextbit Robin, but no matter how many drivers I try, it is not recognized by Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) or Windows (10 x64). First time trying to root, so any advice on this would be appreciated. I have tried drivers from Nextbit and Google, with Nextbit's not doing anything, and Google's impossible to install. The drivers that come with Android Studio cant be install through device manager, with the result of either "Best Drivers Already Installed" if i just select the folder, or "Not made for Windows x64 based platforms" if I use the "Has Disk" button. Any and all advice would be great, thanks!